# Is there a way to turn slack messages into gitlab issues?

Tags: gitlab, slack, slack-api

I'm looking for a way to get messages from our customer support channel on Slack turned into issues in Gitlab as they come in. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could enable the [New issue via mail feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#new-issue-via-email) to allow issues to be created using emails.

You could then use a solution proposed [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82513) to send emails from Slack to the email address that creates issues within Gitlab.